# New codebase version detected

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I've installed CiviCRM 4.6.4 on my WordPress site. But on admin.php page, I get a message box warning me that "New codebase version detected. You might want to visit upgrade screen to upgrade the database."

I visit the upgrade screen which invites me to "Use this utility to upgrade your CiviCRM database from 4.4.6 to 4.6.4."

Doing this produces a series of error messages and corrupts the database:

```
[Error: Migrate honoree information to module_data]
Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_join` ADD COLUMN `module_data` longtext COMMENT 'Json serialized array of data used by the ufjoin.module' [nativecode=1060 ** Duplicate column name 'module_data']
DebugInfo   ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_join` ADD COLUMN `module_data` longtext COMMENT 'Json serialized array of data used by the ufjoin.module' [nativecode=1060 ** Duplicate column name 'module_data']
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
```

Exception trace

```
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  unknown:unknown
1   call_user_func(Array, Object(DB_Error)) /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:931
2   PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error('DB Error: unknow…', -1, 16, Array, 'ALTER TABLE `civ…') /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php:976
3   DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, Array, 'ALTER TABLE `civ…')  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:564
4   PEAR->raiseError(null, -1, null, null, 'ALTER TABLE `civ…', 'DB_Error', true)   /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1905
5   DB_common->raiseError(-1, null, null, null, '1060 ** Duplicat…')    /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php:899
6   DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError() /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php:328
7   DB_mysql->simpleQuery('ALTER TABLE `civ…')  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1216
8   DB_common->query('ALTER TABLE `civ…')   /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2442
9   DB_DataObject->_query('ALTER TABLE `civ…')  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1634
10  DB_DataObject->query('ALTER TABLE `civ…')   /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:325
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('ALTER TABLE `civ…', true)  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1179
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('ALTER TABLE `civ…') /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourFive.php:265
13  CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FourFive::migrateHonoreeInfo(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext)) unknown:unknown
14  call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:88
15  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:213
16  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true) /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:52
17  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:106
18  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))    /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:54
19  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  unknown:unknown
20  call_user_func(Array)   /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:278
21  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:86
22  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:54
23  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1189
24  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   unknown:unknown
25  call_user_func_array(Array, Array)  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-includes/plugin.php:496
26  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /home/coventry/public_html/wpsite/wp-admin/admin.php:226
27  {main}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of working out what's going on?

Many thanks,

David

Answer (score 3):

**On a fresh install, this should not be required.** The reply below is suitable for a site which is seeing this error during an expected upgrade.

---

In `CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourFive.php` (or an included .sql file from there) is an instruction to add a new column to `civicrm_uf_join`

Your DB already contains this column, so CiviCRM runs into trouble when it tries to add it again.

Go back to as pristine a copy of the 4.4 DB as you can, and ensure that column (`civicrm_uf_join.module_data`) does not exist, removing it if it does. Then, re-run the upgrader.

Running upgrades twice on a DB will lead to these sorts of errors, but sometimes applying a patch on a site before upgrade will mean that your DB changes are already applied and need to be eliminated from the following upgrade.

Comment: This is very helpful - thank you. I'm perplexed as to why a brand new installation of 4.6.4 thought it had a 4.4.6 database. Anyway, what I have done in the meantime is to uninstall 4.6.4 and install 4.4.16 instead. When I'm feeling brave - or foolhardy! - I'll try upgrading...

Comment: Looking again at your description - I wonder if somehow your CiviCRM has a typo in the `civicrm_domain` table, reporting 4.4.6 instead of 4.6.4. That would be unfortunate, but it seems plausible. Could someone have directly edited the DB?

Comment: Yes, I agree, a typo seems plausible. But no-one at this end would have edited the database directly. Is it an error in the original download that no-one has noticed? Can I be the only person who has tried to install 4.6.4 into the WordPress environment?!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a brand-new install, there is no need to run upgrades, and attempting to upgrade a 4.6.4 site as if it were 4.4.6 is going to cause errors as you observed.

You could fix this by editing your civicrm_domain sql table to contain the correct version number (look for "4.4.6" and change it to 4.6.4").

As for what caused the problem, it's a mystery to me.